# cant format a hard drive with ubuntu server on it

Tags: format

im currently trying to format a hard drive with ubuntu server but for some reason the hard drive does not want to be read, i here you have to first unmount the partition containing the OS but i can not find exactly how to do with ubuntu server 17. Could someone explain how I can do this please?

Comment: Are you currently booted to the hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your post could include a little more information, but I will just toss this out there as a recommend which *"works for me."* YMMV...

First: When dealing with general formatting of a drive, I like to work from a USB live disk, allowing me full access to the drive in question. If you use the desktop version to get yourself access to gparted or the like, it will allow you to have full access to change the partitions, change the format of the drive etc.

Second: The system will not allow you to format a drive which is currently mounted... If you are currently using swap space or any of the partitions on the drive, it will most likely tell you no...

Third: If you are sure that you are not using the partiton / drive, and it is still telling you no... Are you using root permissions (aka `sudo` etc.)